# Copy text between xml tags using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that would read the text between two different XML tags and write the value to a text file.

The XML looks like:

```
<JobInformation>
<JOB>
<JobName>17Jan_125thou_DEC_B_FullSheet</JobName>
<Date>17 Jan 2017 11:24:34</Date>
<CDI>192.168.0.29</CDI>
<Circumference unit='mm'>1289.94mm</Circumference>
<Laser-Energy unit='J/sqcm'>3.2</Laser-Energy>
<XL-Workflow>XL125_45</XL-Workflow>
<Knife-Type>45 Degree</Knife-Type>
<PREVIEW-    IMAGE>"./images/17Jan_125thou_DEC_B_FullSheet/17Jan_125thou_DEC_B_FullSheet.jpg<    /PREVIEW-IMAGE>
</JOB>
<Plate>
<PlateName>DECx125_20115</PlateName>
<Type>PLATE</Type>
<PlateWidth unit='mm'>2032.0</PlateWidth>
<PlateHeight unit='mm'>1254.94</PlateHeight>
<TotalSize unit='sqm'>2.55</TotalSize>
<Waste unit='sqm'>0.285</Waste>
</Plate>
```

...and so on.

I want to extract the information between tags `<PlateName></PlateName>` and `<Waste></Waste>`.

Also if there is any other way than batch programming please guide. Also I am trying to read lots of XML files in a particular folder but they all have same tags.

The code below reads data from tags `PlateName` but not `Waste`:

```
@echo OFF

del output.txt

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"<PlateName>" *.xml') do call     :job1 "%%i"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i :"<Waste>" *.xml') do call     :job2 "%%i"
goto :eof

:job1

set line=%1

set line=%line:/=%
set line=%line:<=+%
set line=%line:>=+%
set line=%line:*+PlateName+=%
set line=%line:+=&rem.%
echo.%line%>>output.txt

:job2

set line2=%1

set line2=%line2:/=%
set line2=%line2:<=+%
set line2=%line2:>=+%
set line2=%line2:*+Waste+=%
set line2=%line2:+=&rem.%
echo.%line2%>>output.txt

:eof
```

It gives output as:

```
 DECx125_20115
 "17Jan_125thou_DEC_B_FullSheet.xml:&rem.PlateName&rem.DECx125_20115&rem.PlateName&rem."
```

Further into this, how can I edit the code to read only first few characters of the value between the tags? For example: in 313719_V4_DSpotOrange ( 30 Mar 2017 16:50:17 ) I only want to read 313719. Please guide

Comment: PowerShell has powerful XML-parsing capabilities built-in - I would strongly suggest you use that. There are lots of posts about parsing XML in PowerShell on Google.

Comment: There is a typo in 2nd `findstr` command line: `findstr /i /c:"<Waste>"` -- the `/c` option is missing. Insert `goto :eof` between `:job2` and the line above! Your code is searching for the literal string `<Waste>` which does not appear in the XML file; there is only a portion `<Waste unit='sqm'>`...

Comment: @SharvilRaval, you do not put code updates in comments.  Edit your question and remove your comment.

Comment: Now output is DECx125_20115
"17Jan_125thou_DEC_B_FullSheet.xml:&rem.Waste unit='sqm'&rem.0.285&rem.Waste&rem."

Comment: Vbscript, Jscript and Powershell all have native capability to read XML files.

Answer (score 2):

your xml should have one more `</JobInformation>` tag at the end.
You can actually parse the xml to get the data with xpath.Try this script:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off


    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*

    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var objDoc = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
objDoc.load(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));

var objNode = objDoc.selectSingleNode("//"+WScript.Arguments.Item(1));
WScript.Echo(objNode.text);
```

and you can use it like:

```
call getXMLText.bat "xml.xml" Waste
call getXMLText.bat "xml.xml" PlateName
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's always formatted in the same way, you can do it in a much simpler way as follows:

```
@echo OFF

del output.txt

for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"<PlateName>" *.xml') do (
echo %%i>>output.txt
)
for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"<Waste" *.xml') do (
echo %%i>>output.txt
)
```

However, as @RB. says, you're much better off using something with proper XML parsing capabilities. Powershell is one option, VBscript is another.

Comment: You only need one line.  `for /f "delims=<> tokens=3" %%G in ('findstr /i /c:"<PlateName>" /C:"<waste" *.xml') do echo %%G`

Comment: Further into this, how can I edit the code to read only first few characters of the value between the tags? For example: in <ID>313719_V4_DSpotOrange  ( 30 Mar 2017 16:50:17 )</ID>
I only want to read 313719. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expressions in a single `findstr` command:

```
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=<>" %%a in ('findstr "<PlateName>.*</PlateName> <Waste .*>.*</Waste>" *.txt') do (
    echo Found: %%a : %%b
)
```

Output:

```
Found: PlateName : DECx125_20115
Found: Waste unit='sqm' : 0.285
```

---

Also, you wrote:

> Also if there is any other way than batch programming please guide.

There is literally, ANY OTHER WAY to do this that would be better.
Batch-File is the absolute worst at parsing XML accurately.

**C++**, **C#**, **Java**, **Python**, or anything else would be better.